# LibreOffice Calc : conditional execution of a calculation

Tags: conditional-statements, libreoffice, calc

I have a spreadsheet with numerical grades for my students. When a student is missing the day of the test without any valuable reason (like illness), I have to code it with the acronym "ABI", meaning its absence is unjustified.

I want Calc to calculate the mean of each set of student's grades **only** if the student did not miss any test (if any grade is missing, I have to give the "ABI" mark to the sdudent).

I thus created the following formula, but I cannot find a way to force Calc to execute the mean calculation. The IF function seems to only be able to write some text in the cell...

```
=SI(ESTERREUR(EQUIV("ABI";C14:G14;1)); MOYENNE(C14:G14); "ABI")
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("ABI";C14:G14;1)); AVERAGE(C14:G14); "ABI")
```

(I hope I did not do any mistake translating the French keywords into English names).

Whith these formulas, I only got the result VRAI / TRUE instead of a number (if the preceding cells are filled whit numbers), but I got the correct result "ABI" if any of the precedening cells contains "ABI".

I'm under Ubuntu 15.10, with LibreOffice 5.0.2.2.

If someone had an idea... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I entered the formula (translating as "AVERAGE" instead of "MEAN") into a Calc spreadsheet, and it seemed to calculate the value correctly.  Is it giving an error on your system?

Comment: You mean, the whole formula, or the sole command AVERAGE ? In a cell containing **only** the French keyword MOYENNE() (instead of AVERAGE), everything is fine. The difficulty comes when I try to test whether I have an ABI content in a cell or not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Format` -> `Cells` (`Format` -> `Cellules`).  My guess is that the cell of the `VRAI` / `TRUE` value is set to `Boolean Value` (`Valeur logique`).  Change it to `Number` (`Nombre`) instead.

Figure 1: When there is no ABI.
[image: results when data does not contain ABI]

Figure 2: When there is no ABI (French user interface).
[image: results with French user interface]

Figure 3: When there is an ABI.
[image: results when data contains ABI]

Note: At one point there seemed to be some trouble recalculating the formula, because my `Number`-formatted row showed `ABI` while the `Boolean Value`-formatted row showed `TRUE`.  After I changed one of the values again, it recalculated correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right. I don't use Calc that often, and I had no idea that cells could have such parameters. I suppose the type of cells was automatically set to boolean as I was creating the formula step by step.